# Is is possible to calculate the standard error of a percentile using only the mean, standard deviation and count of a sample?

Tags: standard-error, quantiles

Say I have a sample for which I know the standard deviation, the mean and the number of elements in that sample. Using these values, and knowing that the real population is normally distributed, I can calculate the interval in which the real mean of the population lies, with a certain probability.

Using the same values, the mean, count and standard deviation of the sample, can I compute the interval in which the real percentile of a population (let's say p90) lies, with a certain probability?